# /me API endpoint returning 500 error

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, api

I'm making an authenticated call to `/me`:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/me?access_token=[redacted]&site=stackoverflow&key=[redacted]
```

But it's returning:

```
{"error_id":500,"error_name":"internal_error","error_message":"this error has been logged"}
```

My token and key are valid so not sure what's happening.

Any info on this? Perhaps a bug?

Comment: Well, yes this is a bug.  It should be giving you a more sensible error, but it looks like you're sending `['access_token']` instead `access_token`; as in, you're actually sending `[`, `'`, and `]`.

Comment: Ah, my url decoding threw those characters in there and I didn't notice them. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bogus error message has been fixed in the latest deploy (it now correctly reports an `invalid_access_token`).

As to why your request is malformed, refer to my comment above.